# XSL:IF to not repeat a value in an html table column (preceding-sibling?)

Tags: xslt-1.0

In any other language I could just store the previous row's value in a variable and then see if it matches the current value or not, but alas variables in XSL aren't really "variable" or something like that...

So, how do I accomplish what should be an otherwise 'easy' task?

I have some (probably poorly formed) XML, output by a third-party application. I use it to ouput each of the following lines as html table rows using XSL:

```
<xsl:for-each select="Designs/TrackingDetails/Details">

  <tr>
    <th width="200"><xsl:value-of select="./@DGGroup"/></th>
    <th width="350"><xsl:value-of select="./@DGName"/></th>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="./@DGDate"/></td>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="./@DGUser"/></td>
  </tr>

</xsl:for-each>
```

**What I would like is for it to only print each unique 'DGGroup' once**, but it either prints all of them, or nothing at all.

So, in the end, I'd like HTML like this (using XML similar to the bottom of my post):

```
<tr><td>General</td><td>Quote in Date</td><td>04/16/2015</td><td>Ed Garcia</td></tr>
```

and on the next line:

```
<tr><td></td><td>Bid Complete</td><td>04/12/2015</td><td>John Smith</td></tr>
```

Here's some code I've tried so far:

```
<xsl:if test="preceding-sibling::./DGGroup[1]=self::./DGGroup">
```

AND

```
<xsl:if test="preceding-sibling::*[1]=./@DGGroup">
```

...Neither of which work

Here is a sample of some of the XML:

```
<Designs>
<TrackingDetails Transactions_Id="2" Reference="A1234">
<Details DGGroup="General" DGName="Quote in Date" DGDate="04/16/2015" DGUser="Ed Garcia" />
<Details DGGroup="General" DGName="Bid Complete" DGDate="04/12/2015" DGUser="John Smith" />
<Details DGGroup="Design" DGName="Approval Recieved" DGDate="" DGUser="" />
<Details DGGroup="Design" DGName="Design Complete" DGDate="09/18/2015" DGUser="Fred Smith" />
<Details DGGroup="Production" DGName="Released to Production" DGDate="09/18/2015" DGUser="Fred Smith" />
<Details DGGroup="Production" DGName="At Printers" DGDate="" DGUser="" />
<Details DGGroup="Production" DGName="Packaged" DGDate="" DGUser="" />
<Details DGGroup="Delivery" DGName="Delivery Packet Made" DGDate="09/18/2015" DGUser="Fred Smith" />
<Details DGGroup="Invoice" DGName="Invoiced" DGDate="" DGUser="" />
</TrackingDetails>
```

Any ideas? TIA!

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it.
First group the results by DGGroup
Then print the group name only when position = 1

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:key name="groups" match="/TrackingDetails/Details" use="@DGGroup" />

  <xsl:template match="/TrackingDetails">
    <table id="Details">
      <tr class="heading">
        <th scope="col">DGGroup</th>
        <th scope="col">DGName</th>
        <th scope="col">DGDate</th>
        <th scope="col">DGUser</th>
      </tr>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Details[generate-id() = generate-id(key('groups', @DGGroup)[1])]"/>
    </table>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="Details">
      <xsl:for-each select="key('groups', @DGGroup)">
        <tr>
          <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="position()=1">
              <td><xsl:value-of select="@DGGroup"/></td>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
              <td></td>
            </xsl:otherwise>
          </xsl:choose>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="@DGName"/></td>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="@DGDate"/></td>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="@DGUser"/></td>
        </tr>
      </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Question: I currently have a for-each select where I pass a value in like this: /TrackingDetails[@Reference=$currentOT]/Details - where should I add this back in? Add a select to <xsl:template match="/TrackingDetails"> ?

Comment: I think `TrackingDetails` needs to be replaced with `TrackingDetails[@Reference=$currentOT]` wherever it is there (currently on two lines)